# echo base64 image from database php into infowindow google maps output

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a problem regarding my website project. I have stored strings of **base64** images in my online mySQL database, in which i have stored it according to corresponding arrays, along with other data. I want to show the picture in Google Maps InfoWindow. Unfortunately, only the image does not show in the InfoWindow when the marker in the Google Maps has been clicked.

I have tried to input **header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')** inside the coding but it turns out to make the website into a black blank website.

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    <?php 
    if($result2->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>ID : <?php echo $row['id']; ?></h3>' +
            '<p> Latitude : <?php echo $row['latitude']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Longitude : <?php echo $row['longitude']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Type of distress: <?php echo $row['typeofdistress']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Measurement : <?php echo $row['measurement']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Depth : <?php echo $row['depth']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Severity Level : <?php echo $row['severitylevel']; ?></p>'+
            '<p> Solution : <?php echo $row['solution']; ?></p>'+ 
            '<p> Image : </p>'+'<?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .base64_encode($row['image']). '" />'; ?>'+'</div>'],
    <?php }
    }
    ?>
];
```

This below is my snippet of my InfoWindow
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aHqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your image data is already base64 encoded in the database, then you do not need to re encode it.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .$row['image']. '" />';
```

Comment: The picture still doesn't show in the InfoWindow :(